# CollectionViewCell inside of presented ViewController in Xcode 11 distorting cell size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xcode11

I have a `UIViewController` that I present from my main screen, which with Xcode 11 new presentation style, is dismissable by dragging down (modal style). Inside of this view controller there is a collection view with a full width and full height cell inside of which there is an imageView that occupies the whole cell.

My collectionView is meant to be paginated, and has a method sizeForItemAt to make the cell the size of the cell:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
}
```

What happens is that when I scroll past the collection view's content bounds, the cell get completely distorted and I get the following error:

> The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

[image]
[image]

I have read a few posts about it, and I've tried a few things:

- Presenting the UIViewController as full screen (it still distorts the cell when part the horizontal bounds of the collView)
- Changing the content inset adjustment behavior of the collection view to ".never"
- Removing the bounce
- Taking out the image (it does work, as it doesn't distort the cell, but defeats the purpose of design)
- Changed constraints of an image from equal to superview to equal height and width to cell and centered in the cell

I'm really racking my brain as to what can be going wrong, to the point that I might be thinking it might be a bug with Xcode 11's presentation style, however, I have no way to be sure of this.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: How much size is collection view is?Also you can share that particular code . So that i can check upon